# Show that $\lim_{t\to\infty}tm(\{x:f(x)\geq t\})=0$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Trying to solve the Exercise 8.5 of Bass's Analysis book, I want to prove that

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}t\,m(\{x:f(x)\geq t\})=0,$$

where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure and $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x\log(1/x)}$ defined in $[0,1]$.

It is difficult to get the intervals in which $f(x)\geq t$, I think it envolves W-Lambert function, I am trying to get some approximation, but I am stucked. Could you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @OliverDiaz it's defined in $[0,1]$, sorry, edited.

Comment: @Randall it's defined in $[0,1]$, sorry, edited.

Comment: Well surely you cannot have $f(x)$ defined like this for $x=0$ as that would cause division by zero, so the domain of $f$ must be wrong

Comment: @OliverDiaz indeed, however then the domain should technically be $(0,1)$ and not $[0,1]$, no?

Comment: But please be sure to read the comments, because there is a glitch in the posted answer.

Comment: @OliverDiaz but the calculation $m\{x, f(x)\geqslant t\}=x_t=-\frac 1{t\log(x_t)}.$ is not correct, is it? The function has vertical asymptotes at $0$ and $1$ and has a local minimum in $(0,1).$

Comment: @OliverDiaz but $f$ is not strictly increasing on $(0,1)$ so  how can $m\{x, f(x)\geqslant t\}=x_t?$. The claim is true but you need to split up the interval, from $0$  to the local min and from there to $1,$

Comment: Yes, ok. But my point is the original answer does not split the interval up, which I guess you have to do to make the proof go through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather long comment that fits better in this section.

The problem in the aformentioned book in the OP states

> Exercise 8.5 Find a non-negative function $f$ on $[0, 1]$ such that
> $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} t\,m({x:f(x)\geq t})=0$,
> but $f$ is not integrable, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

I gather the OP had a hint and tried to work it out. A similar or related question has beed asked before in MSE (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872067/121671). In his solution, Davide Giraudo considered the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x|\log x|}$ for $x\in (0,1)$. This is not quite the function that solves question 8.5. however, the modification
$$\phi(x):=\frac{1}{x|\log x|}\mathbb{1}_{(0,e^{-1}]}(x) + e\,\mathbb{1}_{(e^{-1},1]}(x)$$
works exactly as explained by Davide.

Comment: Thank you so much! You're right. Indeed, at the version 4.2, there is the function $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x\log(1/x)}$ as an answer in the book. My question could been solved by this function $\phi$, but I am thinking about the book, what do you think? Thank you!

Comment: @Quiet_waters: I added a comment in the answer section showing that the function $f$ you propose does not quite work.