# Which one condition is stronger for random variable $X$?

Tags: probability

Fix a random variable $X$ on $R$. I want to compare two following conditions for $X$:

(1) Assume that $\lim_{x\to \infty}x^4P(|X|\ge x)=0$

(2) Assume that $E[|X|^4]<\infty$.

Which one is stronger?

It seems that there is a counterexample: the distribution whose density $f(x) $ decays as $|x|^{−5}\log|x|$,then it does not have finite fourth moment though condition (1) holds for it.

---

I know that $$ E[X]=\int_R xP(X\ge x).$$ But how about the fourth moment?

Comment: $x^4 P(|X| \geq x) = E(x^4I(|X|^4 \geq x^4)) \leq E(|X|^4I(|X|^4 \geq x^4))$. By the way, the problem is essentially equivalent if you replace 4 with 1.

Comment: (2) implies (1). There are examples where (1) holds but not (2).

Comment: @OliverDíaz Can you explain why? It seems that there is a counterexample: the distribution whose density $f(x) $ decays as $|x|^{−5}\log|x|$,then it does not have finite fourth moment though condition (1) holds for it.

Comment: @Hermi: I think you would be able to  cook-up some examples from this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/872067/121671). But you are on the right track, the logarithm function which grows slowly is helpful.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Thanks! How to prove that (2) implies (1)?

Comment: @Hermi: The Markov-Chebyshev inequality yields $\mu(|X|>\lambda)\leq \frac{1}{\lambda^4}\int_{\{|X|>\lambda\}}|X|^4\,d\mu$. Dominated convergence arguments show that $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\{|X|>\lambda\}}|X|^4\,d\mu=0$.